# What's the best word for a worker's proof of income?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here in Brazil we have the word "*contracheque*". It's an official document an employee receives every month showing his gross income and deductions. Is there anything like it in English?

PS. American English is preferred, because I need it for Johns Hopkins University.

Comment: Paycheck: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paycheck

Comment: You need this word for Johns Hopkins University??  or do you mean that they’ve asked for you to provide proof and you are now  responding and want to say, “Here is the < *word* > you’ve requested.” If the latter, why not repeat the word(s) they used when asking you for it?

Comment: There are various ways in Britain (and I suspect it is not much different in America) that one can provide proof of income. One would be for you to supply them with copies of your payslips (paychecks). Another,  would be for them to write to your employer asking for confirmation of information you have given them about your pay. There is no particular word which describes any such document. But it could form part of an *employer's reference*.

Comment: "Pay stub" would be the semi-formal term in the US, meaning either the "stub" from a paycheck or an equivalent document.

Comment: Let's not forget 'under the table', the payslip-of-choice for many!

Comment: In the U.S. this is called *either* "pay stub" *or* "pay slip".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly mean a "payslip" (payment slip)

> "a piece of paper received by an employee showing how much salary they have been paid." [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/payslip)
>
> "a note given to an employee when they have been paid, detailing the amount of pay given, and the tax and insurance deducted. [**OD**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/payslip)

- Payslips give important information about earnings and deductions.

Answer (score 5):

You could mean **pay stub**, which shows how much you received in a [paycheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck) but is not a check itself.

You might also mean [W2 form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_W-2), which shows a calendar year's worth of earnings. This is typically only for the income tax folks, rather than, for instance, a company deciding whether to offer you credit.